# Permit params for has_one nested attributes does not applied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, nested-attributes

Model class:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :data, inverse_of: :user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :data
end
```

Posted body

> {data: {active: false}, data_attributes: {active: false}, nickname: "nick"}

Rails Log

> Parameters: {"data"=>{"active"=>false}, "data_attributes"=>{"active"=>false}, "nickname"=>"nick", "id"=>"1", "user"=>{"nickname"=>"nick"}}

params:

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"data"=>{"active"=>false}, "data_attributes"=>{"active"=>false}, "nickname"=>"nick", "controller"=>"api/users", "action"=>"update", "id"=>"1", "user"=>{"nickname"=>"nick"}} permitted: false>
```

params.require(:user).permit(:nickname, data_attributes: [:active])

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"nickname"=>"nick"} permitted: true>
```

User.new(a)

```
#<User id: nil, provider: "email", uid: "", name: nil, nickname: "nick", image: nil, email: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

User.new(a).data

```
nil
```

What's wrong. Is it right beahaviour?
What need to fix to nested data object properly create?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data hash should be like this:

{user: {active: false}, data_attributes: {active: false}, nickname: "nick"}

Problem is that your hash is:

```
Parameters: {"data"=>{"active"=>false}, "data_attributes"=>{"active"=>false}, "nickname"=>"nick", "id"=>"1", "user"=>{"nickname"=>"nick"}}
```

It should be:

```
Parameters: {"user"=>{"nickname"=>"nick", "id"=>"1","data_attributes"=>{"active"=>false}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that parameters for nested models are wrapped by default. You probably have to either wrap them under the "user" key yourself, or tell your controller which parameters it should wrap explicitly.

The first option should be handled by your form (or JS library if you're doing AJAX requests).

The second option is something along the lines of

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  wrap_parameters :user, include: [:data_attributes]
  def create
    # now you can access params[:user][:data_attributes]
  end
end
```

Refer to the documentation on [ActionController::ParamsWrapper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ParamsWrapper.html) and this [Rails issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/17216) for further details.